# Write a no-op or dummy class in Python

Tags: python

Let's say I have code like this:

```
foo = fooFactory.create()
```

For various reasons, `fooFactory.create()` could fail to create an instance of `Foo`.

If it does, I want `fooFactory.create()` to return a dummy/no-op object. This object should be completely inert - no matter how it is used, it should not do anything or throw any exceptions. Note that `foo` does not have methods that return values.

---

I've considered the following options.

First, create a **mock**. The upside of this is that it's easy and gives me exactly what I want. The downside is that it feels odd to use a mock in production code. More importantly, I have no control over the mock library and so its behavior could change at some point and break my application.

Second, create a **dummy** `NoopFoo`/ `DummyFoo` class. I then manually implement the methods it needs to support, and just put `pass` in the method bodies. The upside of that I know it will never break my application. The downside is that if other methods of `Foo` are used in future, I have to know to update `NoopFoo`/ `DummyFoo` ... or my application may break.

Is there a better option than either of these? Note that I'm new to Python so if it involves more advanced Python features, I would appreciate a little more information. Thanks!

Comment: You might want to rethink your design. The factory function should either return `None` or raise an exception. Returning a non-functional but apparently valid object is just asking for trouble.

Comment: Whilst I agree with Rob, if your hands are tied I would use `mock`, it sounds like the closest match to your requirements. Otherwise you are reinventing the wheel.

Comment: "Will never break my application" might not be true in any case, depending on your usage. If you're assigning new functions dynamically, like "foo.bar = lambda whatever" then dummies could still be given working functions later on. It would be much more difficult to build a guaranteed-dummy class than a 'probably-dummy' class

Comment: @en_Knight See my solution then. Any assignment will be silently ignored.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You ask for an object that does nothing. An instance of `object` does precisely that.

```
def create():
    return object()
```

On the other hand, you might actually want it to do something. You might want it to have methods that execute and return `None`. You might return an instance of this class:

```
In [1]: class Nop(object):
   ...:     def nop(*args, **kw): pass
   ...:     def __getattr__(self, _): return self.nop
   ...:     

In [2]: n=Nop()

In [3]: n.foo
Out[3]: <bound method Nop.nop of <__main__.Nop object at 0x7f9fec034650>>

In [4]: n.foo()

In [5]: n.foo(1,2,3)
```

Comment: This does not meet the requirement in the question: "This object should be completely inert - no matter how it is used, it should not do anything *or throw any exceptions*"

Comment: @PeterGibson This is about as inert as it gets.

Comment: @PeterGibson How do you avoid that a method call does not do anything? At least it has to return something.

Comment: @ChristianK. It could always just loop :)

Comment: The requirement, as stated, is impossible to meet. The best we can do is to answer the question he should have asked.

Comment: @ChristianK. perhaps, but then the answer should probably explain that issue. Your answer is a better response to the question in my opinion

Comment: @Robᵩ probably you are right - but I'm guessing that code is out of OP's control.

Answer (score 10):

How about this one:

```
class MayBeCalled(object):
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return None

class Dummy(object):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return MayBeCalled()

    def __setattr__(self, attr, val):
        pass

a = Dummy()

print a.nn
<__main__.MayBeCalled object at 0x103ca9a90>

print a.nn()
None

a.nn = 23
print a.nn()

None
```

A Dummy object responds to any attribute access doing nothing.

Answer (score 5):

The previous answers with dummy objects don't work with nested attributes/methods. Here is my solution:

```py
class Dummy:

    def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
        pass

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self

    def __getattr__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self
```

Now we can access nested attributes and methods:

```py
>>> d = Dummy()

>>> d.my_attr
<__main__.Dummy object at 0x10d007160>

>>> d.my_method()
<__main__.Dummy object at 0x10d007160>

>>> d.my_attr.my_method()
<__main__.Dummy object at 0x10d007160>

>>> d.my_attr.my_other_attr
<__main__.Dummy object at 0x10d007160>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the  [`nop`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nop/) package, available via `pip install nop`. Please do not use the `mock` package instead (except in tests) because it stores call history!

```
from nop import NOP

dummy = NOP()

dummy.foo()
NOP
dummy.foo().bar()
NOP
dummy.foo('x', 'y')
NOP
dummy.foo('x', 'y', z=3)
NOP

type(_)
<class 'nop.nop_base.NOP'>
```

Its source code is [here](https://bitbucket.org/invalidhandle/nop/src).

Comment: I know it's old, but it also doesn't cover everything - e.g. class variables:
`nop.NOP.CLASSVAR` -> `AttributeError: type object 'NOP' has no attribute 'CLASSVAR`
Any solution for that?

Comment: @daten As per your demonstrated usage, you are using it wrong. The answer to your question is already in the answer.