# Creating copy of globals()

Tags: python, python-3.x, copy, global, deep-copy

In python, I'm trying to write a utility function to time how long functions take to run. It's basically a helper function that makes working with `timeit` easier.

Here's my code. If any of it seems strange, it's because I tried to trim as much of the code as I could and make it as simple as possible:

```py
import numpy as np
import timeit
import requests
from enum import Enum
import copy


class LoggingLevel(Enum):
    Debug = 1
    Info = 2
    Important = 3
    VeryImportant = 4
    SuperImportant = 5
    Warning = 6


class Logging:

    @staticmethod
    def log(message: str, level: LoggingLevel, special, colorized):
        colors = {
            "Debug": "\033[0m",
            "Info": "\033[94m",
            "Important": "\033[95m",
            "VeryImportant": "\033[96m",
            "SuperImportant": "\033[93m",
            "Warning": "\033[91m",
            "Special": "\033[92m",
            "reset": "\033[0m"
        }
        if colorized:
            if special:
                print(f"{colors['Special']}[{level.name}] [Special]: {message}{colors['reset']}")
            else:
                if level.name in colors:
                    print(f"{colors[level.name]}[{level.name}]: {message}{colors['reset']}")
                else:
                    print(f"[{level.name}]: {message}")


logging = Logging()


def check_internet(testurl: str = "https://www.example.com", timeout: float = 5) -> bool:
    logging.log("Checking for internet connection with timeout of"
                f" {timeout if timeout is not None else ''} seconds...",
                LoggingLevel.Info, special=False, colorized=True)
    logging.log(f"Using {testurl} to check for internet connection", LoggingLevel.Debug, special=False, colorized=True)
    try:
        requests.get(testurl, timeout=timeout)
        logging.log(f"Successfully confirmed internet connection!", LoggingLevel.Info, special=False, colorized=True)
        return True
    except (requests.ConnectionError, requests.Timeout):
        return False


def time(code: str, useglobals: bool = True, sets: int = 3, trialsperset: int = 10) -> float:
    """
    Times how long a segment of code takes to run (on average) using the timeit module
    Usually used to test functions

    :param code: The segment of code to test
    :param useglobals: Whether to use the current globals or no globals in the
    timing sandbox (the code may not work without them)
    :param sets: The number of sets
    :param trialsperset: The number of times to run the code each set
    (Total number of times run = sets * trials)
        the higher the number, the more accurate, but also the longer it will take
    :return: Average amount of time the code takes to run (seconds)

    """

    # noinspection IncorrectFormatting
    class NopClass:
        """ From https://stackoverflow.com/a/24946360/20558255 """

        def nop(*args, **kwargs): pass

        def __getattr__(self, _): return self.nop

    nopclass = NopClass()
    nopfunction: callable = lambda *args, **kwargs: None

    logging.log(f"Testing how long {code} takes to run in {sets} sets"
                f" of {trialsperset} trials...", LoggingLevel.Debug, special=False, colorized=True)
    if useglobals:
        sandboxglobals = copy.deepcopy(globals())
        # We nop logging class and print function so we don't get flooded with print messages
        sandboxglobals["print"] = nopfunction
        sandboxglobals["logging"] = nopclass
    else:
        sandboxglobals = None
    times = timeit.repeat(stmt=code, repeat=sets, number=trialsperset, globals=sandboxglobals)
    return np.mean(times)

time("check_internet()", useglobals=True, sets=3, trialsperset=10)
```

Hopefully you can understand why I (try to) copy `globals()` into `sandboxglobals` and make some changes to `sandboxglobals`, then pass `sandboxglobals` to `timeit.repeat`: I want to disable printing and logging for the code *when it is being timed*. However, I don't want to disable printing and logging for the real program. Though in this case it would be okay to disable printing and logging for the real program before calling `timeit.repeat()` then re-enable them after, in other cases (asynchronous or multithreaded code, for example), it would matter.

However, `deepcopy` doesn't work. When I run the code, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test.py", line 98, in <module>
    time("check_internet()", useglobals=True, sets=3, trialsperset=10)
  File "Test.py", line 87, in time
    sandboxglobals = copy.deepcopy(globals())
  File "C:\Users\zachy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\copy.py", line 146, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "C:\Users\zachy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\copy.py", line 231, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "C:\Users\zachy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\copy.py", line 161, in deepcopy
    rv = reductor(4)
TypeError: cannot pickle 'module' object
```

I understand what this error is saying, but I don't know how to work around it. I tried everything I could find, but I was unable to find a way to deep copy without pickling.

Shallow copy does not work because it is not recursive - it will disable`print`, because this is top-level in the `globals()` dict, but it won't disable `logging.log`. As proof, here's the log after changing `deepcopy` to `copy`:

```
[Debug]: Testing how long check_internet() takes to run in 3 sets of 10 trials...
[Info]: Checking for internet connection with timeout of 5 seconds...
[Debug]: Using https://www.example.com to check for internet connection
[Info]: Successfully confirmed internet connection!
[Info]: Checking for internet connection with timeout of 5 seconds...
[Debug]: Using https://www.example.com to check for internet connection
[Info]: Successfully confirmed internet connection!
... [TRUNCATED]
```

Is there any way to achieve what I want? Or is it impossible? Is there something I'm missing?
Thanks.

Comment: If you want to temporarily modify what the names of `print` and `logging` refer to, why not simply do that and leave `globals` alone?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille
I addressed this in my question:

`However, I don't want to disable printing and logging for the real program. Though in this case it would be okay to disable printing and logging for the real program before calling timeit.repeat() then re-enable them after, in other cases (asynchronous or multithreaded code, for example), it would matter.`

Comment: Even if you pass a "sandboxed" version of `globals()` to `timeit`, that won't actually help you. First, it's the wrong globals - you need the caller's globals, not your `time` function's globals - and second, it won't affect the global namespace used by `check_internet` or any code `check_internet` calls.

Comment: @user2357112 Can you please rephrase that or elaborate? I don't understand any of that. Why is it "the wrong globals"? What are my time function's globals? What does the `caller` refer to in "my caller's globals"? "What does `it won't affect the globlal namespace` mean? I don't want the code executed by `timeit.repeat` to change the state of my real program from. Sorry if I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: Suppose you've got your `time` function in one module `time_module`, and a function `f` in another module `f_module` that you want to time. From `f_module`, you `import time_module` and run `time_module.time('f()', useglobals=True))`. `time_module.time` is going to try to look up `f` in (a copy of) `time_module`'s global namespace instead of `f_module`'s global namespace. That's how it's the wrong globals.

Comment: As for the other part, if you get past the pickle problems you're currently having, you'll find that your `check_internet` function still does all the logging you didn't want it to do, because none of your globals fiddling affects the global namespace `check_internet` itself performs global lookups in.

Comment: @user2357112 Ok, I get what you mean now. The [current answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75957163/20558255) was able to solve the pickle problems, so now I'm stuck on the second problem. What you said is exactly what's happening, and I've suspected that the whole way through. But isn't `deepcopy`'s job to copy absolutely everything? Shouldn't that affect the namespace `check_internet` performs global lookups in? If not, how can I achieve this?

Comment: And yes, your described scenario is *exactly* what's happening - I just shortened the code into one file. My `logging` class (and `LoggingLevel` enum) actually lives in a module (`logger.py`), and I'm using `from logger import logging, LoggingLevel` to import it.

Comment: "But isn't deepcopy's job to copy absolutely everything?" - first, no. `deepcopy`'s job is to copy deeply, not to copy absolutely everything. Second, nothing in your code actually tells `check_internet` to *use* the copy you created. In fact, Python has no API for changing the namespace a function performs global name lookups in. You can kind of get around that by creating a new function with a different global namespace, but that doesn't affect any other functions that function calls, so actually getting this to work is a huge mess and not really practical.

Comment: (And no, `globals=sandboxglobals` doesn't tell `check_internet` to use `sandboxglobals`. It only affects the namespace used for your `"check_internet()"` snippet that calls `check_internet`. It doesn't affect the namespace `check_internet` itself uses.)

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not need to do any modification with modules info in `sandboxglobals`, you can skip deepcopying them from `globals`.

```py
# noinspection IncorrectFormatting
    class NopClass:
        """ From https://stackoverflow.com/a/24946360/20558255 """

        def nop(*args, **kwargs): pass

        def __getattr__(self, _): return self.nop

    nopclass = NopClass()
    nopfunction: callable = lambda *args, **kwargs: None

    logging.log(f"Testing how long {code} takes to run in {sets} sets"
                f" of {trialsperset} trials...", LoggingLevel.Debug, special=False, colorized=True)
    if useglobals:
        sandboxglobals = {}
        for k,v in globals().items():
            try:
                # entries of modules raise exception
                # do not deepcopy them
                tmp_dict = copy.deepcopy({k:v})
                sandboxglobals.update(tmp_dict)
            except:
                tmp_dict = {k:v}
                sandboxglobals.update(tmp_dict)
        # We nop logging class and print function so we don't get flooded with print messages
        sandboxglobals["print"] = nopfunction
        sandboxglobals["logging"] = nopclass
    else:
        sandboxglobals = None
    times = timeit.repeat(stmt=code, repeat=sets, number=trialsperset, globals=sandboxglobals)
    return np.mean(times)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. It helps, but unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work. To troubleshoot, I added this code:<br> `print(id(globals()["logging"].log))
            print(id(sandboxglobals["logging"].log))` after the nopping code (<br>`  sandboxglobals["logging"] = nopclass`<br>). The results were strange:<br> The ids were the same for `time(f"""logging.log('Hi')""")` , but different for `time("""check_internet()""")`.<br> I don't understand this weird behavior - it must be some shenanigins with `copy.deepcopy`. Any ideas?

Comment: Oops, apparently mini-Markdown doesn't support line breaks. If my comment is too ugly to read, you can use a [markdown viewer](https://markdownlivepreview.com/)